How to estimate the integral of the exponential of a rational trigonometric function
I am trying to estimate (from above) the following integral:
$$\int_0^\pi \exp\left(a\sin(\vartheta)+b\cos(\vartheta)-\frac c{\sin(\vartheta)}\right)d\vartheta,$$
where $a,b\in \mathbb R$ and $c\in\mathbb R_+$. I am particularly interested in its behaviour as $|a|+|b|\to \infty$ (i.e. the point $(a,b)$ escapes to infinity)
Unfortunately, it seems hopeless for that integral to have a closed form and my attempts at producing a nontrivial "asymptotic" estimate: Jensen's inequality only gives a trivial estimate and the trivial estimate $\le \pi\exp(\max)$ did not really lead anywhere as trying to find an expression for the maximum of the exponent does not seem feasible (one quickly gets a 3rd degree trigonometric equation to solve). Similarly, trying the trick of turning this into a contour integral has not lead me anywhere. Any help (even for particular values of $a,b,c$) would be greatly appreciated.

You can use Laplace's Method 
It is  convenient to write  the two parameters $a$ and $b$ in their polar coordinate form as $a= -M \sin s , b= M \cos s$.
Then $a \sin x+ b \cos x =M \cos (x-s)$
We want an asymptotic approximation valid as $M\to \infty$ for the integral
$ I=\int_0^{\pi} e^{M g(x)} h(x) dx $ where $g(x)= \cos(x-s)$ and $h(x)=e^{-c/sin(x)}$.
Note that the maximum value of $g(x)$  is located at the critical point $x_0=s$. Below we focus on the case where this peak value at $x_0=s$ lies in the given interval of integration: that is, $s\in [0,\pi]$
As described in the link to Laplace's Method,the  asymptotic behavior of your integral is given by
$$I\approx \sqrt{\frac{ 2\pi}{M |g''(x_0)|}}  e^{Mg(x_0)} h(x_0)$$
Here $x_0=s$, $g(x_0)=1$,
$g''(x_0)  =-1$, and $h(x_0)= e^{- c/sin s}$
so
$$I\approx \sqrt{\frac{ 2\pi}{M }} e^M e^{- c\csc s}$$
P.S. In the degenerate endpoint cases where either $s=0$ or $s=\pi$, the same general theory works but you only see half of the peaking factor $e^{M (g(x)}$ within the window of integration, so in this case the answer is half of that quoted above.
